# What are some results in mathematics that have snappy proofs using model theory?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, big-list

I am preparing to teach a short course on "applied model theory" at UGA this summer.  To draw people in, I am looking to create a BIG LIST of results in mathematics that have nice proofs using model theory.  (I do not require that model theory be the first or only proof of the result in question.)

I will begin with some examples of my own (the attribution is for the model-theoretic proof, not the result itself).

1. An injective regular map from a complex variety to itself is surjective (Ax).
2. The projection of a constructible set is constructible (Tarski).
3. Solution of Hilbert's 17th problem (Tarski?).
4. p-adic fields are "almost C_2" (Ax-Kochen).
5. "Almost" every rationally connected variety over Q_p^{unr} has a rational point (Duesler-Knecht).
6. Mordell-Lang in positive characteristic (Hrushovski).
7. Nonstandard analysis (Robinson).

[But better would be: a particular result in analysis which has a snappy nonstandard proof.]

**Added**: The course was given in July of 2010.  So far as I am concerned, it went well.  If you are interested, the notes are available at

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/MATH8900.html](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/MATH8900.html)

Thanks to everyone who answered the question.  I enjoyed and learned from all of the answers, even though (unsurprisingly) many of them could not be included in this introductory half-course.  I am still interested in hearing about snappy applications of model theory, so further answers are most welcome.

Comment: The last chapter of the new edition of Courant and Robbins' "What is Mathematics?" has an appendix in which Ian Stewart gives a sketch of nonstandard analysis and spectacular applications to proofs in analysis.

Comment: Since the question has already bumped, I have replaced the dead link by a working one. Still, I will point out that if you go to that website, the links to the pdf-files are in the "old format" and you'll need to modify them to get a working link. See also [a related post on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34750/suggestion-to-mass-replace-links-to-http-math-uga-edu-pete).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is a consequence of the model completeness of algebraically closed fields.

Edit: I don't have a reference, but I can sketch the proof. Suppose you have some polynomial equations that don't have a solution over ${\mathbb C}$. Extend ${\mathbb C}$ by a formal solution, and then algebraically close to get a field $K$. The field $K$ obviously contains a solution, but by model completeness of algebraically closed fields, a first-order statement is true in an algebraically closed field only if it is true in every algebraically closed subfield that contains all its parameters. The existence of a solution to a finite set of polynomial equations is a first-order statement (whose parameters are the coefficients) and ${\mathbb C}$ is algebraically closed. QED.

Comment: Again, could you provide a reference?  Thanks.

Comment: A good, brief reference is the very first pages of David Marker's notes on Model Theory of Fields. See http://www.math.uic.edu/~marker/mtf-reading.html

Also, Kevin, I'm not really happy with your proof summary: as you note, it is a consequence of model completeness of ACF. But then you say that "a first-order statement is true in an algebraically closed field only if it is true in every algebraically closed field", and this property is NOT model completeness, it is simply completeness. (And moreover, ACF is model complete but not complete, ACF_p is complete though.) 

Comment: Let me briefly explain why I like this example best (for now!).  First, the application is to a theorem which is important and mainstream (especially here in Athens, where algebraic geometry is popular).  Second, the model-theoretic argument seems insightful and in some ways more geometric than the standard proofs: it is essentially a generic points argument.  I plan to use it in my lectures, and I'll post notes...several months from now.

Comment: The conclusion of the proof sketch is incorrect as stated since the coefficients of the given polynomials are not arbitrary. However, model completeness does show that polynomials equations with coefficients in C have common solution in some extension K, then they must have a common solution in C since C is an elementary submodel of K; this gives a correct conclusion.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Isn't char(K)=p a first-order statement which is true of some algebraically-closed fields but not others?

Comment: @GM: Yes, that's right.  The theory of algebraically closed fields is *model complete*, which is closely related to completeness but neither implies nor is implied by it.  Together with the existence of prime models it implies completeness, so this shows that the theory of algebraicially closed fields of given characteristic $p \geq 0$ is complete.  

Comment: This argument only works for a *finite* set of polynomials. In order to prove Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz in its full generality, one has to appeal to Hilbert’s basis theorem first.

Comment: Since I didn't find it quite clear how this would prove the Nullstellensatz, here is a link with a complete proof: https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Ford.pdf

Answer (score 48):

Plane geometry is decidable. That is, we have a computable algorithm that will tell us the truth or falsity of any geometrical statement in the cartesian plane.

This is a consequence of Tarski's theorem showing that the theory of real closed fields admits elimination of quantifiers. The elimination algorithm is effective and so the theory is decidable. Thus, we have a computable procedure to determine the truth of any first order statement in the structure (R,+,.,0,1,<). The point is that all the classical concepts of plane geometry, in any finite dimension, are expressible in this language.

Personally, I find the fact that plane geometry has been proven decidable to be a profound human achievement. After all, for millennia mathematicians have struggled with geometry, and we now have developed a computable algorithm that will in principle answer any question.

I admit that I have been guilty, however, of grandiose over-statement of the situation---when I taught my first logic course at UC Berkeley, after I explained the theorem some of my students proceeded to their next class, a geometry class with Charles Pugh, and a little while later he came knocking on my door, asking what I meant by telling the students "geometry is finished!". So I was embarrassed.

Of course, the algorithm is not feasible--its double exponential time. Nevertheless, the fact that there is an algorithm at all seems amazing to me. To be sure, I am even more surprised that geometers so often seem unaware of the fact that they are studying a decidable theory.

Comment: This is doubtless rather subjective, but I would call the completeness of geometry a theorem of meta-mathematics.  The trouble is, as you point out, that it does not seem to lead to a quicker or better understanding of any particular geometric fact.  

Comment: I am not sure exactly how you would like to divide model theory and meta-mathematics, but surely this topic fits naturally into a discussion of elimination of quantifiers, which would seem to be an important part of model theory, no?  About your second comment, alas, it is true. Nevertheless, I shall wax poetic about the significance of our having come to a great enough understanding of geometry that we have a decision procedure. 

Comment: @JDH: Sure, I include model theory as part of meta-mathematics.  The point is that I am trying to draw in an audience that has no prior experience with meta-mathematics of any kind, model-theoretic or otherwise.  Therefore I want to give examples of theorems which can be cleanly stated without any meta-mathematical concepts.  I cannot assume that my audience even knows what decidability means.

Comment: By "plane geometry is decidable", do you mean that there is an algorithm to prove (using Euclid's axioms? or something else?) or disprove any (well-formed) statement about plane geometry? Determining truth/falsity is not the same as finding a proof/disproof, right? Also, what do you mean by "all the classical concepts of plane geometry, in any finite dimension", doesn't plane geometry just mean dimension 2?

Comment: @Kevin Lin: Tarski proved that there is an algorithm to decide the truth or falsity of any first order statement in the real-closed field (R,+,l,0,<). The concepts of points, lines, planes, circles, conics, spheres, paraboloids, etc. are all expressible in this language, using the usual polynomials. Thus, we have a decision procedure for Cartesian (as opposed to Euclidean) geometry. And the algorithm handles any R^n simply by working with coordinates. 

Comment: Tarski's concept of plane geometry is both more and less than
Euclid's concept. More, because it includes curves other than
lines and circles. Less, because it doesn't admit integer variables.
A famous open problem implicit in Euclid is: for which n is the
regular n-gon constructible?

Comment: @John: I agree. Once you allow quantification over integers, then Tarski's theorem breaks down completely, and undecidability reigns again. Indeed, one get undecidability even for assertions having just a single integer quantifier, since this is enough to express the halting problem. 

Comment: @Kevin Lin: Well, naturally, determining truth/falsity is the same thing as finding a proof/disproof from whatever system validates the method by which you determined truth/falsity.

But, anyway, in this particular case, we can speak much less abstractly: Tarski proved that the axioms for a real closed field decide every first-order statement in their language (i.e., either prove it xor prove its negation). So, there you go: a simple theory that you're already familiar with was shown by Tarski to settle all the questions of suitable form.

(I realize now I'm replying to an ancient thread)

Comment: Should the term "plane geometry" in the post be circumscribed? There are various axiomatic systems for Euclidean geometry; for example there are Hilbert's axioms which include completeness axioms (not first-order), and there are Tarski's axioms for elementary Euclidean geometry which *are* first-order (and closely tied to the first-order theory of real closed fields, as explained in his paper *What is Elementary Geometry?*). I suppose you have the latter in mind, but if so, it seems reasonable to make this point explicit in the post.

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but Tychonoff's theorem has a snappy two line proof in the non-standard setting once the non-standard characterization of compact is established. The non-standard characterization of compactness says that $X$ is compact if and only if every $x\in X^*$ is infinitely close to some standard point in $X$ and infinitely close is defined in terms of the monads of the topology.

Edit: (**Tychonoff**) $X := \prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is compact if and only if each $X_i$ is compact.

The forward direction is easy and does not require any non-standard analysis. Simply use the projection maps.

Now suppose all the $X_i$ are compact and let $y\in X^*$ then $y(i^*)\in (X_i)^*$. Since $X_i$ is compact there is some $x(i)\in st(y(i^*))$ and we can take $x\in X$ to be the product of the points $x(i)$. By construction $x^*\approx y$ and this establishes the backward direction.

The above theorem along with its non-standard proof can be found in "Nonstandard Analysis" by Martin V$\ddot{a}$th on page 166 but I'm sure any other book on the subject will include a proof of the theorem using pretty much the same terminology and concepts.

**Notation**: $(-)^*$ is the extension map, $st(-)$ is the standard part map, and $\approx$ is the relation defined in terms of the monads of the topology.

Comment: Could you give some more specifics and/or a reference?

Comment: The `usual' proof via ultrafilters is very similar, so I do not think that you gain anything here by using non-standard analysis. 

Comment: Also, the 'usual' proof that uses nets instead of ultrafilters is even more similar to this one...

Comment: The forward direction only holds when all $X_i$ are non-empty.

Comment: The proof is not from me. IIRC, Luxemburg had observed it already in the 60's in some paper in which he proved the Tychonoff theorem for Hausdorff spaces using only the boolean prime ideal theorem instead of the axiom of choice: For Hausdorff spaces, st is a function, and so no additional invoking of AC is necessary - having a nonstandard model is sufficient, and for that in turn the boolean prime ideal is sufficient, at least in this case.

Answer (score 11):

You can prove Gromov's Theorem on groups of polynomial growth. See ven den Dries and Wilkie, Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth and elementary logic, J Algebra, 89 (1984), 391-396.

Answer (score 11):

I guess this one is a bit too late for this summer, but the theory of o-minimal structures greatly simplified proofs in real algebraic and subanalytic geometry, by emphasizing concepts over nitty-gritty details (at the cost of a loss of constructivity, of course, but what can you expect?).

It is worth noting that these two structures are the ones for which the o-minimal property was known *before* the notion itself was formalized.  Many more have been discovered since then, the most noteworthy being probably the real exponential field [(Wilkie)](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-04/S0894-0347-96-00216-0/).

Answer (score 11):

Alan Dow and others have explored the use of elementary submodels in Topology. See e.g. [his introductory paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=author%3Aa-dow+introduction+elementary+submodels+topology) [here](https://webpages.uncc.edu/adow/Ftp/Intro.Elem.Subm/elem.ps) or [here](https://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v13/tp13102.pdf). One application: the theorem by Arhangel'lskij that a Hausdorff Lindelöf first countable space is at most size continuum. There is a technical proof using transfinite recursion (the standard one), but also a slick one using elementary submodels (of sufficiently large countable models of ZFC).

Answer (score 10):

There are many results in Banach space theory that are proved via ultraproducts or non standard hulls, and most books on the subject contain a few.  One nice one that is easy to state is that a Banach space that is uniformly homeomorphic to a Hilbert space is linearly homeomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 9):

This one https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2190 is brand new. ".... For a simple linear group G, we show that a finite subset X with |X X<sup>-1</sup> X |/ |X| bounded is close to a finite subgroup, or else to a subset of a proper algebraic subgroup of G....". I understand that people in additive combinatorics consider it useful.

Answer (score 9):

Hilbert's Seventeenth Problem: Let $f \in \mathbb{R}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ be a rational function which is positive everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exist rational functions $g_1$, $g_2$, ..., $g_N$ such that $f=\sum g_i^2$.

Proof sketch: Let $K$ be the field $\mathbb{R}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. If $f$ is not a sum of squares, then there is a total ordering of $K$ where $f$ is negative. Let $L$ be the real closure of $K$ with respect to that ordering. Then the rational function $f$, evaluated at the point $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in L^n$, is negative. But the theory of real closed fields is complete, so $f$ must be negative somewhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, contrary to hypothesis.

See Jacobson *Basic Algebra II* for a detailed exposition.

Comment: David -- yes, it's a nice application.  But please look again at the question...

Comment: I searched the page for "seventeenth" and "sum of squares". Are you telling me I have to read it with my eyes as well? :)

Answer (score 8):

You can find lots of other applications just by browsing the titles of the papers on the [MODNET preprint server](http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/modnet/Home/) (follow this link and look under "Publications" on the left side of the page).  For example:

1. "The monomorphism problem in free groups", by L. Ciobanu and A. Ould Houcine (in which they show it is decidable);
2. "An invitation to model-theoretic Galois theory," by A. Medvedev and Ramin Takloo-Bighash -- expository paper explaining how the Galois correspondence can be explained using model theoretic tools;
3. "On algebraic closure in pseudofinite fields," by O. Beyarslan and E. Hrushovski;

etc.

Also, there is a recent book *Model Theory with Applications to Algebra and Analysis: v. 1* (LMS Lecture Note series v. 349, Cambridge, 2008) which would probably be very relevant (judging by the table of contents -- unfortunately I haven't had a chance to read it yet).

Answer (score 8):

I like what I've heard about this 2005 GAFA paper on topological dynamics by Kechris-Pestov-Todorcevic:
[Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00039-005-0503-1)

It uses the Fraïssé limit construction to produce a family of topological groups with interesting universal minimal flows.

Comment: Title of the linked reference:  [Fraïssé Limits, Ramsey Theory, and topological dynamics of automorphism groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00039-005-0503-1).

Answer (score 7):

1. For a particular result in analysis with a snappy non-standard proof, there's [this proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7642/tropicalizing-the-learning/7684#7684) of the Bieri-Groves Theorem on tropical amoebas.  (Does this count as "analysis"?  I'm not sure.)
2. There are some nice applications of model theory to [differential Galois theory],[2](http://www.math.uic.edu/~marker/sev.pdf) partly due to the fact that the complete theory of differentially closed fields of characteristic zero happens to have extremely nice model theoretic properties (it's omega-stable, hence there nice rank functions on definable sets and unique-up-to-isomorphism prime models over any set of parameters).

Comment: Here's a link to a paper on differential Galois theory (for some reason it wasn't letting me add the link to my answer): http://www.math.uic.edu/~marker/sev.pdf

Answer (score 7):

There is a proof of a p-adic birational version of Grothendieck's Section Conjecture by Jochen Koenigsmann using Model theory: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305226
I'm not entirely sure, but I think there is no known (published?) proof of this result not using model theory.

Answer (score 7):

Two more examples of applications:

The paper by Hrushovski arXiv:math/0406514v1 gives an application of Model Theory to a conjecture by Jacobi on difference equations.

The paper by Cluckers, Hales and Loeser arXiv:0712.0708 gives an application of Model Theory to the Fundamental Lemma in Langlands Theory.

Answer (score 7):

1. I think the Manin-Mumford Conjecture proofs first used some methods of Model theory, before it was finally proved by Raynaud. I am not able to dig up references, though.
2. Yuri Manin and people who worked in relation with him, posted many papers on arXiv relating the problem of getting Mordell-Weil type theorems in higher dimensions, i.e., on cubic surfaces etc.. One of the references is https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0223

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget the beautiful theory of motivic integration, initiated by Maxim Kontsevich at an Orsay seminar, and developed by Jan Denef, François Loeser, Raf Cluckers, Julien Sebag and many others. The theory is becoming increasingly important.

The crucial, first paper by Denef and Loeser:

Denef & Loeser,

["Germs of arcs on singular algebraic varieties and motivic integration" (Inventiones Mathematicae 1999)](http://www.wis.kuleuven.ac.be/wis/algebra/denef_papers/GermsArcs.ps)

Another standard reference which should be readable - "In writing the paper we tried our best keeping it accessible to a wide audience including algebraic geometers and model theorists":

Cluckers & Loeser,

["Constructible motivic functions and motivic integration" (Inventiones Mathematicae 2008)](http://uk.arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0410/0410203v3.pdf)

A very nice overview of some applications:

[Loeser's slides for his ECM plenary lecture](http://www.dma.ens.fr/~loeser/ecm_fl_final.pdf)

Comment: @AS: I am looking for particular results with relatively elementary statements.  I am epsilon familiar with the work of Denef and Loeser but am concerned that it is too advanced/technical to draw out a result which is accessible to a general graduate student audience (perhaps somewhat slanted towards algebra / algebraic geometry / number theory).  Can you extract a particular result from one of these papers which meets these requirements?

Comment: Hm, you could mention the recent applications to the fundamental lemma (Cluckers-Loeser-Hales). The result might be understandable (clearly the proof won't).

Or you could mention the rationality result for Poincaré series (see Denef's 1984 paper - this is not motivic integration, strictly speaking, but uses quantifier elimination) or Batyrev's result that birational Calabi-Yau varieties have equal Betti numbers, a big motivation for the development of the theory.

Comment: You will find a very clear and understandable overview in Loeser's slides for his ECM plenary lecture: http://www.dma.ens.fr/~loeser/ecm_fl_final.pdf


Comment: @AS: The rationality result for Poincare series and the birational invariance of Betti numbers of Calabi-Yaus are both within the scope of understanding of portions of my target audience.  Thanks very much for suggesting them.

Comment: The links are broken...

Answer (score 7):

Recently Pillay and his student Nagloo tackled transcendence questions about the famous Painlevé equations. They entirely use model theory:

[Nagloo and Pillay - On algebraic relations between solutions of a generic Painlevé equation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2916)

[Nagloo and Pillay - On the algebraic independence of generic Painlevé transcendents](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1562)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to dig up such an old question, but I wanted to mention some more applications of Model theory that has perhaps been not covered in the other answers:

1) Using the basic algebraic fact that given a field $\mathbb F$ and finitely many polynomials $f_1,...,f_n \in \mathbb F[X]$, there is a field extension $\mathbb K_{|\mathbb F}$ in which all the $f_i$ s has a root; one can show by using the Compactness theorem  , that given a field $\mathbb F$, there is a field extension $\mathbb L_{|\mathbb F}$ in which every polynomial $f \in \mathbb F[X]$ has a root. This in turn can be used iteratively to build an algebraically closed field extension $\mathbb K_{|\mathbb F}$ . Then taking the field of all elements of $\mathbb K$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb F$, we get an algebraic extension of $\mathbb F$ which is algebraically closed i.e. we get an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F$. The Compactness theorem can also be used to prove the uniqueness of algebraic closure.

2) The first order theory of Real Closed fields in the language of ordered fields has quantifier elimination. This can be easily used to prove certain facts about " semi-algebraic sets" (i.e. sets which are Boolean combination i.e. finite union , intersection and compliment of sets of the form $\{\bar x : p(\bar x) =0\}$ and $\{\bar x : p(\bar x) <0\}$, where $<$ is the canonical order on a real closed field and $p$ is a multivariate polynomial with coefficients in the field)

(i) If $\mathbb F$ is a real closed field and $f: \mathbb F^m \to \mathbb F^n$ is a semi-algebraic function (the graph of the function is a semi-algebraic set) , then $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are semi-algebraic for any semi-algebraic sets $A \subseteq \mathbb F^m ,  B\subseteq \mathbb F^n$. This is often called the generalized Tarski-Seidenberg theorem.

(ii)  Every non-negative element in a real closed field is the square of a unique non-negative element; this defines the square root of a non-negative element. For a real closed field $\mathbb F$, using the $\mathbb F$-valued norm $|(x_1,...,x_n)|:=\sqrt {x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$ on $\mathbb F^n$ , we get a topology on $\mathbb F^n$. Using quantifier elimination, it can be easily shown that the closure (under the above mentioned topology) of any semi-algebraic set is again semi-algebraic.

(iii) the theory of RCF has quantifier elimination and has a prime model, hence it is a complete theory. Using this it can be shown that If $\mathbb F$ is a Real closed field and $f : \mathbb F^m \to \mathbb F^n  $ is a continuous (w.r.t. the topology ) semi-algebraic function, then $f$ carries closed and bounded sets to closed and bounded sets (bounded in the sense of the $\mathbb F$-valued norm).

(iv) Using the completeness of RCF and quantifier elimination , it can also be shown that if $f: \mathbb F \to \mathbb F$ is semi-algebraic , then for any open-interval $U\subseteq \mathbb F$, there is $x \in U$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

And there are many more similar results.

Comment: Can you clarify (or give a reference) how the compactness theorem can be used to prove the uniqueness of an algebraic closure ? (I only knew the first bit, i.e. it can prove its existence)

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at at a nice short introduction to "modern" "applied" [model theory](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/~zilber/modth.pdf). 
Perhaps it could be used to prepare to teach a short course on "applied model theory" at UGA this summer.

Comment: The link `http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/~zilber/modth.pdf` seems to be dead - I did not find it [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2021*/http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/~zilber/modth.pdf), either.