# Computability of fillability of unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $k$ $\varepsilon$-balls

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, computability-theory, decidability, computable-analysis

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. We define a relation $R \subseteq \mathbb{N}^4$ in the following way:

> $(p,q,n,s)\in R$ if and only if there is $S\subseteq [0,1]^n$ with $|S| = s$ such that for all $x\in [0,1]^n$ there is $y\in S$ such that $\| x-y \|< \frac{p}{q}$.

**Question.** Is $R\subseteq \mathbb{N}^4$ computable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers

Comment: Observe that $(p,q,n,s)\in R$ precisely when there is some $S\subseteq[0,1]^n$ with $|S|=s$ and $d(S,[0,1]^n)<\frac{p}{q}$ where $d$ denotes the Hausdorff metric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question whether $(p,q,n,s)\in R$ in any instance can be expressed as a sentence in the language of the structure $\langle\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0,1,<\rangle$, a real-closed field, and by Tarski's theorem on real closed fields, there is a  computable uniform decision procedure to decide the truth of all such sentences.

See further description at [my answer to a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/134260/1946).

Comment: Can you briefly describe how you get around the fact that you are quantifying over the dimension (which you mention in your linked answer as something you're "not allowed to do")?

Comment: @KevinCasto Yes, this is a subtle point. Each particular instance statement $(p,q,n,s)\in R$ does not quantify over the dimension. Different statements have different dimensions $n$, yes, but given any input $(p,q,n,s)$, I can write down the sentence in the language of ordered fields, and ask the Tarski algorithm if it is true.